# Rings with an epimorphism to $\mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I was wandering about rings which has a factor ring isomorphic with $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Rings which can be split into two parts like the integers which splits in even and odds. There are many such rings, for example the integers, polynomials with integer coefficients, rings of integers of number fields, boolean rings. Is there a name for rings with this property? Some partial or whole classification?

Comment: When you say epimorphism do you mean surjection? These are not the same in the category of rings!

Comment: oh yes, i mean surjection

Comment: I assume you are talking about the unital ring order 2, $\Bbb{Z}/(2)$, rather than about the $2$-adic integers $\Bbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: Rings which exists a surjective homomorphism from the ring to integers modulo 2, $\Bbb{Z}/(2)$